# If $A=(X)$, $B=(Y)$ are ideals of a ring, then $A+B=(X\cup Y)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Suppose $R$ is a ring that has an identity, and $A=(X)$, $B=(Y)$ are two ideals of $R$. Does
$$
A+B = (X\cup Y)
$$
hold?

Here $(X)$ denote the ideal generated by $X\subset R$ as a subset, and
$$
A+B = \{a+b\colon a\in A, b\in B\}.
$$

Comment: There are two inclusions. Have you tried checking if either of them hold? If so, where do you get stuck?

Comment: I had proved neither. Actually, what is confusing me is what explicitly is the meaning of the ideal generated by a subset. I was wondering $(X)$ is the set of all finite sums of finite products of elements in $X$, but it soon proves to be wrong. I'm tryring the method that if $X\cup Y\subset C$, where $C$ is an ideal, then $A+B\subset C$.

Comment: Yes, that is a valid strategy: use that $(X)$ is the smallest ideal of $R$ containing the set $X$. Also note that $A+B$ is the smallest ideal of $R$ containing both $A$ and $B$. Together, these facts should be all you need.

Comment: That's brilliant, cheers!